# How can you add an integer to the value of 'i' in a for loop?

Tags: c#, html, for-loop, razor

I have a C# for loop incorporated as razor code into a webpage. This HTML segment will be generated
until the condition (`i < Model.RecentArticles.Count`) becomes false. But if you know anything about for loops you probably already knew that.

My issue is that I wish to set the IDs of the div element to be like such: `grid_1`, `grid_2`, `grid_3`, etc. for each consecutive div the code produces.

However since `i` starts as 0 (this cannot be changed because doing so would skip the first row in the database) the divs will be given the IDs `grid_0`, `grid_1`, `grid_2`, etc.

I figured this would be easy to fix, I would just change the razor code in the ID parameter to read `id="grid_@{i+1;}"`. Unfortunately, this results in an error and have no idea whether I have made some sort of syntax error or if what I am trying to do it not possible. I am very new to C# and razor so I suspect I have just made a silly mistake somewhere.

```
@for (int i = 0; i < Model.RecentArticles.Count; i++)
{
    <div class='section_list' id="grid_@{i+1;}">Article</div>
}
```

Comment: Use parentheses instead of curly brackets and remove the semicolon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
@for (int i = 0; i < Model.RecentArticles.Count; i++)
{
    <div class='section_list' id="grid_@(i + 1)">Article</div>
}
```